# Why isn't my website displaying after uploading index.html to cPanel?

Tags: html, css, cpanel, web-hosting

I just bought a domain and hosting from GoDaddy and I'm trying to get the website displaying properly.  I have uploaded all of folders (img, css, etc) to public/html as well as my index.html file but when I try to access the website it still says "Coming Soon"  Is there another step I have to do to actually publish the website?

Comment: You should most definitely contact GoDaddy's customer support team

Comment: try downloading the file that you hosted and see if you uploaded the right ones.

Comment: Ask GoDaddy for further support, there may be extra steps. You'll need to make sure the DNS servers are setup properly and it's resolving to the right place. It may come online within 24 hours anyway. Sometimes it's just a matter of waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Your domain is pointing to different path from the path where physical files of the site are placed.
If the site-URL is an add-on domain or a sub-domain make sure that the files are in the directory that has the same name as the site-URL.

Try adding "index.html" after the site-URL.
For ex : xyz.com/index.html.

I hope it helps.